# Real-analytic fibre bundle via surjective submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Lately I came across the following lemma (in Michor "Topics in Differential Geometry", p. 200, Lemma 17.2):

> Let $p: M\rightarrow N$ be a surjective submersion which is proper and let $N$ be connected. Then $(M, p, N)$ is a (smooth) fibre bundle.

The proof relies heavily on partition of unity, which does not exist in the (real-)analytic case. Therefore, my question is:

> Are there sufficient conditions such that the lemma is true in the (real-)analytic category?

Comment: You are asking for sufficient conditions but do you know a counter-example ? Michèle Audin states that it fails in real-analytic category but doesn't give such example.

Comment: @N.H. I don't know any counterexample. If it still holds in the real-analytic category, then I'll happily award the bounty to anyone providing a reference that the sufficient condition is in fact vacuous :)

Comment: Ok, I think sadly it doesn't hold : page 36 of "Hamiltonian Systems and Their Integrability" Michèle Audin states [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=_w3tkgrlsScC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=michele+audin+real+analytic+fibration&source=bl&ots=wZ3Dk9wGYA&sig=TAtCyILuuvC2CTbRhyOESpUUQ5A&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGm5Sbx8fUAhXM1RQKHZDeB0EQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) that there are real analytic families which are not analytically trivial, but sadly don't provide any more details.

Comment: This lemma is false in complex analytic category. Not so sure about real analytic case.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Do you know a counterexample in the complex analytic case?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes, I can post them.

Comment: @MoisheCohen That would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, I will address the complex-analytic version of this question. In short, the classical theory of **moduli spaces** is build around such examples.

The key (trivial) observation is that if $\pi: E\to M$ is a (locally holomorphically trivial) holomorphic bundle with connected base manifold $M$, then for  all $x\in M$ the fibers $\pi^{-1}(X)$ are all biholomorphic to each other. (To see this, first observe that this holds locally on $M$ and then it holds globally on $M$ since $M$ is connected).

Now, let $M_g$ denote the moduli space of compact Riemann surfaces of genus $g\ge 1$. The complex space $M_g$ is an orbifold (a Deligne-Mumford stack) but at generic points $M_g$ is a complex manifold of dimension $3g-3$ (if $g\ge 2$) or $1$ if $g=1$. Genericity of $X\in M_g$ is understood as triviality of the group of automorphisms of $X$ if $g\ge 3$ and the equality of $Aut(X)$ to the order 2 group generated by the hyperelliptic involution if $g\le 2$.

Over $M_g$ we have the **universal curve** $\pi: U\to M_g$ whose fiber over a Riemann surface $X\in M_g$ is biholomorphic to $X$. The mapping $\pi$ is a holomorphic submersion over generic points of $M_g$.  However, fibers $\pi^{-1}(X)$ are all pairwise non-isomorphic.

One can get more concrete examples by looking at the genus $g=1$ case, see e.g. [these noted by Dick Hain](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1803.pdf). Here is another example (due to Kodaira). Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g\ge 2$, let $\alpha: X\to X$ be an automorphism without fixed points; consider the diagonal embedding $\Delta$ of $X$ into $X^2$ and let $A\subset X^2$ denote the graph of $\alpha$. Then $\Delta$ and $A$ are disjoint. There exists a 2-fold branched cover $p: M\to X^2$ ramified over $\Delta \cup A$. The composition $\pi$ of $p$ and the projection $X^2\to X$ is a holomorphic submersion. However, $\pi: M\to X$ is a locally nontrivial fibration. The fiber $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is a 2-fold branched cover over $X$ ramified over the points $x, \alpha(x)$.

Edit. As for local triviality in the real-analytic setting, it might be true. Grauert proved uniqueness of real-analytic structures on manifolds (with fixed underlying smooth structure), see

H. Grauert, H., 1958, On Levi'sproblemand the imbedding o freal analytic manifolds, Annals Math. 68, 460-472.

More precisely, Grauert proved that every real-analytic manifold embeds in some $R^N$, while Whitney proved earlier that in the embedded setting the real-analytic structure is unique (using Weierstrass approximation theorem).

Maybe Grauert-Whitney proof can be used to prove local triviality for real-analytic proper submersions.

**Edit.** 1. The reference to Whitney's proof is:

H. Whitney, Differentiable manifolds. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 37 (1936), no. 3, 645–680.

2. See also

K. Shiga, [Some aspects of real-analytic manifolds and differentiable manifolds](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jmath1948/16/2/16_2_128/_pdf). J. Math. Soc. Japan 16 (1964) 128–142.

Among other things, he reproves Whitney's theorem and has some results about proper analytic submersions which, I think, yield a positive answer to your original question. Namely, look at his Theorem 3 and apply it in your setting. We already know that $p: M\to N$ is locally trivial as $C^\infty$ bundle. In other words, there is a family of open subsets $U_i\subset N$  and $C^\infty$-diffeomorphisms $M_i:=p^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i\times F$, where $F$ is some fixed (real analytic) manifold. Shiga's theorem 3 gives you a real-analytic diffeomorphism $\phi_i: M_i\to U_i\times F$ which preserves the bundle structure.  Thus, the maps $\phi_i$ provide a real-analytic local trivialization for $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. Do you know a reference for the uniqueness of the real-analytic case by Whitney?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: See the edit; it also contains, I think, an answer to your original question.

Comment: Amazing! With this you answered several questions of mine.